# substr_replace encoding in PHP

Tags: php, encoding, fwrite

I want to write to a text file. When I use *[substr_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php)* in PHP, the encoding changes. It doesn't print Greek Characters correctly. If I don't, everything is fine. How can I fix this?

```
<?php
    $file = "test.txt";
    $writeFile = fopen($file, "w+"); // Read/write
    $myarray = array("δφδφ", "δφδσφδσ", "δφδφδ");
    $myarray[0] = substr_replace($myarray[0], "ε", 0, 1);

    foreach ($myarray as $data) {
        fwrite($writeFile, $data . "\n");
    }
?>
```

#### Outcome

ε�φδφ
δφδσφδσ
δφδφδ

***Outcome without any*** *substr_replace()*

δφδφ
δφδσφδσ
δφδφδ

Comment: You can try this multibyte function http://lv.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php#59544

Comment: You must use multibyte functions to do what you want in this case. A plain `substr_replace` only works on the data as a binary string - without caring for encoding.

Answer (score 19):

You can use these two functions:

From [shkspr.mobi](https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2012/09/a-utf-8-aware-substr_replace-for-use-in-app-net/):

```
function mb_substr_replace($original, $replacement, $position, $length)
{
    $startString = mb_substr($original, 0, $position, "UTF-8");
    $endString = mb_substr($original, $position + $length, mb_strlen($original), "UTF-8");

    $out = $startString . $replacement . $endString;

    return $out;
}
```

---

From [GitHub](https://github.com/fluxbb/utf8/blob/master/functions/substr_replace.php):

```
function mb_substr_replace($str, $repl, $start, $length = null)
{
    preg_match_all('/./us', $str, $ar);
    preg_match_all('/./us', $repl, $rar);
    $length = is_int($length) ? $length : utf8_strlen($str);
    array_splice($ar[0], $start, $length, $rar[0]);
    return implode($ar[0]);
}
```

I tried both and both work well.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're encoding the Greek in a multi-byte encoding (like UTF-8), this won't work because the core PHP string functions, including `substr_replace`, are not multi-byte aware. They treat one character as equal to one byte, which means you'll end up slicing multi-byte characters in half if you only replace their first byte. You need to use a more manual approach involving a multi-byte aware string function like [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/mb_substr):

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
echo 'ε' . mb_substr('δφδφ', 1);
```

[The comment @arma links to](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php#59544) in the comments wraps that functionality in a function.

Answer (score 3):

Try this version:

```
function mb_substr_replace ($string, $replacement, $start, $length = 0) 
{
    if (is_array($string)) 
    {
        foreach ($string as $i => $val)
        {
            $repl = is_array ($replacement) ? $replacement[$i] : $replacement;
            $st   = is_array ($start) ? $start[$i] : $start;
            $len  = is_array ($length) ? $length[$i] : $length;

            $string[$i] = mb_substr_replace ($val, $repl, $st, $len);
        }

        return $string;
    }

    $result  = mb_substr ($string, 0, $start, 'UTF-8');
    $result .= $replacement;

    if ($length > 0) {
        $result .= mb_substr ($string, ($start+$length+1), mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8');
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: this function is buggy

Comment: Care to explain @evilReiko?

Comment: I tried it, it worked fine, but then I noticed that sometimes it removes the first character after replacement

Comment: @evilReiko The first character of $replacement?

Comment: I think so (it's been few days since I last tried this function)

Comment: I read in comments that this function is buggy. Is it right? Did you try it @EdsonMedina?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `mb_convert_encoding()` function to set the correct encoding.

Answer (score 0):

```
function replace($string, $replacement, $start, $length = 0)
{
    $result  = mb_substr($string, 0, $start, 'UTF-8');
    $result .= $replacement;

    if ($length > 0)
    {
        $result .= mb_substr($string, ($start + $length), null, 'UTF-8');
    }

    return $result;
}
```